# What is the publickey for in nsswitch.conf

Tags: glibc, nsswitch

As I understand it the `getent` tool is used to query the Name Service Switch. In the `getent` man file all the different entries (plus a few more) from `nsswitch.conf` is listed, *except* the publickey one. And indeed, if I try `getent publickey foo` I the error is `Unknown database: publickey`

In the `nsswitch.conf` man page the publickey entry is described as:

> Public and secret keys for Secure_RPC used by NFS and NIS+.

The [GNU docs on the subject](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/NSS-Basics.html#NSS-Basics) don't really clear anything up. They just say that publickey is among databases that will be "added later."

I tried installing the os `nis` package, but still can't find any clues to or examples of how this nss entry is supposed to be used.

I am running Archlinux `5.2.10` glibc `2.29`